# port clean does nothin

Tags: macos, port

Hi I am trying to remove a package on mac OS. I want to uninstall "ettercap". When I run 
`port installed | grep ettercap`
I get :   `ettercap @0.8.0_2+gtk+plugins (active)`
I then run `port clean ettercap`
but when I run again `port installed | grep ettercap`, the package is still here. Do you have an idea of what is going on?
Thank you!